# Add id to input

Tags: javascript

I have this input: `<input type="text" name="1">`.

Using vanilla JS how can I assign an id to it? To make it look like this: `<input type="text" name="1" id="2">`.

Have this so far, does not work, and I cannot find out why...

```
var xyz = document.getElementsByName(1");
xyz.setAttribute("id", "2");
```

Comment: You're missing a " before the 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns array. You need set attribute to single element. Hack: `xyz[0].setAttribute...`

Comment: Using hardcoded value is a bad idea. What if the page have many elements with same name?

Answer (score 1):

As VeroLom said,

> getElementsByName returns array.

So you have to return only one element :

```
var xyz = document.getElementsByName(1")[0]; // there, I pick the first element of the array
xyz.setAttribute("id", "2");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var xyz = document.getElementsByName("myName");
xyz[0].id = "myId";
```

or

```
xyz[0].setAttribute("id", "myId");
```

Please notice that [IDs and names can't start wit a number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata).

Answer (score 1):

They function `.getElementsByName(1)` returns an array of HTML DOM object with the name 1.

To access the first element try this:

```
xyz = document.getElementsByName("1")[0];
xyz.setAttribute("id", "2");
```

and by the way, ID's should start with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xyz = document.getElementsByName(1");
xyz.setAttribute("id", "2");
```

This gives you an array of elements by name "1". So you need to traverse and give id to each element.

So, if you are sure you have only one element with this name you can do

```
 var xyz = document.getElementsByName("1")[0];
 xyz.setAttribute("id", "2");
```

Comment: missing `"` at `..(1")[0];`